# RabbitMQ create connection is an expensive operation

Tags: rabbitmq

is creating a connection in RabbtiMQ .net client an expensive operation?

We have a Web application that publishes message to the RMQ, and currently we create and close the connection on every publish.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, creating connection is expensive. Why are you creating and closing connection to rabbit anyway after publish?

I would suggest create rabbit connection once, then close it whenever you need to.

Comment: It might be because the docs seem to illustrate that: http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.12.0/examples/comparing_publishing_sync_async.html

Answer (score 1):

If you maintained a single connection it would be faster to send messages, as you would only need one operation to send a message.  Opening a connection each time uses io resources so is bound to be a little slower.